# In spring-batch when is an ItemWriter invoked?

Tags: spring-batch

I remember reading that `ItemWriter.write()` will be invoked periodically. What does this mean? Is it invoked every `x` milliseconds, where `x` is a configurable constant? Or is it invoked every `n` items? What happens if one processor thread is blocked waiting for a condition and `n` is not reached yet, and it's the only pending item left? Does the writer get invoked?

I have a case where the processor needs to wait for another item to be written to ensure processing integrity. Can I rely on the writer being invoked regardless of the situation (while a processor is waiting, blocked in the `process()` method)?

EDIT :

My problem is that some items need to be deferred when another pending item (not written yet) that meets a certain condition (can't give too much detail) is detected. The processor should wait until that other item is written. The problem occurs when the writer is waiting for the commit item count to be reached, and one or more processors are waiting for the processed items to be written which creates a deadlock. If there is a way of explicitly flushing the writer (or setting a timeout that invokes the writer even if the item count is not reached yet) my problem would be solved.

Comment: You can set `commit-interval` to `1` with a cost of efficiency. Or you can implement your own `Processor` or `Writer` to control process flow.

Comment: I can't sacrifice efficiency. And the customization I have in mind for the writer and processor are too complicated to my liking. We use spring batch to simplify parallelization, I only need a mechanism for deferring certain items which spring batch doesn't seem to provide. I can control what the writer does and what the processor does but I have very little control over when they get invoked.

Answer (score 0):

The number of processed items before running writer is 'commit-interval' (on your xml job configuration).

ItemWriter implementation will use results of ItemProcessor method. 
Of course, an processed item could be blocked forever if it is waiting for an item located in the same chunk.

Could you bring us more details about your problem ?

Comment: My problem is that some items need to be deferred when another pending item (not written yet) that meets a certain condition (can't give too much detail) is detected. The processor should wait until that other item is written. The problem occurs when the writer is waiting for the commit item count to be reached, and one or more processors are waiting for the processed items to be written which creates a deadlock. If there is a way of explicitly flushing the writer (or setting a timeout that invokes the writer even if the item count is not reached yet) my problem would be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Batch's item processing isn't intended for what you're attempting.  We either offer everything being processed pretty much in order (fault tolerant cases not withstanding), or no guarantee of order (through the various multi-threaded options).  From the scenario you are describing, you really have two options:

1. **Break this into two steps** - Is there a reason you can't process the delayed items in a second step after the dependent items are processed?
2. **Roll your own** - The `Tasklet` interface is there for this very reason.  If one of the patterns provided by Spring Batch doesn't cover what you need, you can write your own logic into your own `Tasklet`.